# Service Bus Trigger using variable values for topic and subscription not firing

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a relatively simple Azure function that pulls messages from a Service Bus based on a topic and subscription name - this works perfectly when debugging locally but once deployed, the function simply doesn't trigger. There are no errors, and messages continue to sit on the Service Bus untouched.

The function itself just pulls the message off the topic, deserialises it and passes the resulting object to a service that will add/update a CosmosDB item.

```csharp
[FunctionName("PullFromServiceBus")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] string message)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {message}");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(message);
    await AddOrUpdate(obj);
}
```

And in the application settings on the Azure portal, I have settings called "TopicName" and "SubscriptionName" that contain the values I need.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867324/referencing-environment-variable-for-topic-name-in-servicebustrigger) that corroborates my approach should be correct but I can't work out why the function doesn't trigger. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you check the logs, anything interesting ? Is it possible that there is another processor de-queuing the messages as well ?

Comment: No logs, nothing. This is the only function that's tied to that particular topic at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps anyone else who has the same issue. I believe this was a deployment issue as this was caused by a missing line in the extensions.json file in the bin folder of the function app.

After adding the following line to extensions.json, the trigger started working without any further changes.

```json
{ "name": "ServiceBus", "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusWebJobsStartup, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"%TopicName%"` just try to send "TopicName" which is the actual topic name in the app setting.

Chances are that the trigger is looking for the topic with name `%TopicName%` instead of the one in the app settings.

You refer the following [article](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-app-setting-azure-functions/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20different%20ways%20to%20access%20the%20App,make%20a%20few%20changes%20in%20the%20local.settings.json%20file.) on how to use app setting in functions.

Comment: I could hardcode the topic and subscription name in the code sure, and I know that works, but that completely defeats the purpose of putting it into configuration. Not only that, but this doesn't answer the question